# Rendering of page before data from useEffect is recieved

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm building a webshop with React, typescript and a self-made API.

I'm trying to get the Cart component to work. It fetches from the API the ID's of the products, and based on those it fetches the products with those ID's, and puts the products in the array dinosArray.

Now, I'm trying to render a new row in the table for each product in the dinosArray. My problem is just that the mapping and thereby rendering of the rows happen before the dinosArray is populated - resulting in no rows added since the dinosArray is empty when being mapped over.

How do I achieve my goal of rendering a new row in the table based on each entry in the dinosArray?

Below is the code of the component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Table } from "react-bootstrap";
import "../css/stylesheet.css";

export default function Cart() {
  var dinosArray: any = []



  const getProducts = async () => {
    let apiUrl = "http://localhost:3005/velocishop/customers/" + localStorage.uuid + "/baskets/" + localStorage.uuid + "/products"
    let response = await fetch(apiUrl)
    let products = await response.json()
    console.log("this is products")
    console.log(products)
    products.map((product: any) => {
      fetchDino(product)
    })
    console.log("this is dinosArray")
    console.log(dinosArray)
  }


  function fetchDino(product: number) {
    console.log("in fetchDino")
    var url: string = "http://localhost:3005/velocishop/products/" + product
    fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }).then(response => {
      if (response.ok)
        return Promise.resolve({ status: response.statusText }) && response.json()
      else
        return response.json()
    }
    )
      .then(response => JSON.stringify(response))
      .then(response => JSON.parse(response))
      .then(data => dinosArray.push(data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))

    //renderProducts()
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getProducts()
  }, [])

  function renderProducts() {

    console.log("in renderProducts(), this is dinosArray:")
    console.log(dinosArray)

    return (
      <div>
        {dinosArray.map((dino: any) => (
          <tr>
            <td>{dino.productName}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </div>
    )

  }


  return (
    <div className="register-wrapper">
      <Table responsive="sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><h1 className="italic-header">Products in cart</h1></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {renderProducts()}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use *state*.

*State* is a value that a component has, which cause the component to re-render when new state is set.

So in this case, change this:

```
var dinosArray: any = []
```

To:

```
const [dinosArray, setDinosArray] = useState([])
```

Now you call `setDinosArray(myNewDinosArray)` whenever you have new data.

---

Next, change this:

```
.then(data => dinosArray.push(data))
```

To:

```
.then(data => setDinosArray(dinosArray => [...dinosArray, data])
```

Since you have many async functions that are updating this state, you can pass a function to `setDinosArray` which always get the current state as the first argument. That means you will always have the most up to date `dinosArray` every time you go to add something to it.

---

State is a foundational pillar of React, and you should read more about in the official documention:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried implementing what you are suggesting. However, when replacing .then(data => dinosArray.push(data)) with .then(data => setDinosArray(dinosArray => [...dinosArray, data]), it won't compile and shows the error "Argument of type '(dinosArray: never[]) => any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
  Type '(dinosArray: never[]) => any[]' is not assignable to type '(prevState: never[]) => never[]'.
    Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
      Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'." Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: I fixed the error by adding this type to the useState: const [dinosArray, setDinosArray] = useState<any>([])

Comment: That `any` should be the shape of a single dino object. Such as `useState<{ species: string, period: 'jurassic' | 'cretaceous' }[]>([])` It's important to use strong types so that Typescript can do what it does best.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use useState hook. instead of `var dinosArray: any = []`, you can define `const [dinosArray, setDinosArray] = useState([]);` and on where you did `dinosArray.push(data)` you can do somethink like `setDinosArray([...dinosArray, data])`

Answer (score 0):

You have imported the useState hook but you're not using it. Add it to your component and set it when response.ok === true in the following lines

```
if (response.ok)
        return Promise.resolve({ status: response.statusText }) && response.json()
      else
        return response.json()
```

You can use the value returned by that hook to decide what to render